# Resample DICOM Images to Size and Spacing and align to same Origin

Tags: python, simpleitk

I have a set of 4 DICOM CT Volumes which I am reading with SimpleITK ImageSeriesReader. Two of the images represent the CT of patient before and after the surgery. The other two images are binary segmentation masks segmented on the former 2 CT images. The segmentations are a ROI of their source CT.

All the 4 CT images, have different Size, Spacing, Origin and Direction. I have tried applying this GitHub gist https://gist.github.com/zivy/79d7ee0490faee1156c1277a78e4a4c4 to resize my images to 512x512x512 and Spacing 1x1x1. However, it doesn't place the images at the correct location. The segmented structure is always placed in the center of the CT image, instead of the correct location, as you can see from the pictures.

This my "raw" DICOM Image with its tumor segmentation (orange blob).

[image]

This is after the "resizing" algorithm and writing to disk (same image as before, just the tumor is colored green blob because inconsistency):
[image]

**Code used for resampling all 4 DICOM Volumes to the same dimensions:**

```
def resize_resample_images(images):
    """ Resize all the images to the same dimensions, spacing and origin.
        Usage: newImage = resize_image(source_img_plan, source_img_validation, ROI(ablation/tumor)_mask)
        1. translate to same origin
        2. largest number of slices and interpolate the others.
        3. same resolution 1x1x1 mm3 - resample
        4. (physical space)
        Slice Thickness (0018,0050)
        ImagePositionPatient (0020,0032)
        ImageOrientationPatient (0020,0037)
        PixelSpacing (0028,0030)
        Frame Of Reference UID (0020,0052)
    """
    # %% Define tuple to store the images
    tuple_resized_imgs = collections.namedtuple('tuple_resized_imgs',
                                                ['img_plan',
                                                 'img_validation',
                                                 'ablation_mask',
                                                 'tumor_mask'])
    # %% Create Reference image with zero origin, identity direction cosine matrix and isotropic dimension
    dimension = images.img_plan.GetDimension()  #
    reference_direction = np.identity(dimension).flatten()
    reference_size = [512] * dimension
    reference_origin = np.zeros(dimension)
    data = [images.img_plan, images.img_validation, images.ablation_mask, images.tumor_mask]

    reference_spacing = np.ones(dimension) # resize to isotropic size
    reference_image = sitk.Image(reference_size, images.img_plan.GetPixelIDValue())
    reference_image.SetOrigin(reference_origin)
    reference_image.SetSpacing(reference_spacing)
    reference_image.SetDirection(reference_direction)
    reference_center = np.array(
        reference_image.TransformContinuousIndexToPhysicalPoint(np.array(reference_image.GetSize()) / 2.0))

    #%% Paste the GT segmentation masks before transformation
    tumor_mask_paste = (paste_roi_image(images.img_plan, images.tumor_mask))
    ablation_mask_paste = (paste_roi_image(images.img_validation, images.ablation_mask))
    images.tumor_mask = tumor_mask_paste
    images.ablation_mask = ablation_mask_paste


    # %%  Apply transforms
    data_resized = []
    for idx,img in enumerate(data):
        transform = sitk.AffineTransform(dimension) # use affine transform with 3 dimensions
        transform.SetMatrix(img.GetDirection()) # set the cosine direction matrix
        # TODO: check translation when computing the segmentations
        transform.SetTranslation(np.array(img.GetOrigin()) - reference_origin) # set the translation.
        # Modify the transformation to align the centers of the original and reference image instead of their origins.
        centering_transform = sitk.TranslationTransform(dimension)
        img_center = np.array(img.TransformContinuousIndexToPhysicalPoint(np.array(img.GetSize()) / 2.0))
        centering_transform.SetOffset(np.array(transform.GetInverse().TransformPoint(img_center) - reference_center))
        centered_transform = sitk.Transform(transform)
        centered_transform.AddTransform(centering_transform)
        # Using the linear interpolator as these are intensity images, if there is a need to resample a ground truth
        # segmentation then the segmentation image should be resampled using the NearestNeighbor interpolator so that
        # no new labels are introduced.

        if (idx==1 or idx==2): # temporary solution to resample the GT image with NearestNeighbour
            resampled_img = sitk.Resample(img, reference_image, centered_transform, sitk.sitkNearestNeighbor, 0.0)

        else:
             resampled_img = sitk.Resample(img, reference_image, centered_transform, sitk.sitkLinear, 0.0)
        # append to list
        data_resized.append(resampled_img)


    # assuming the order stays the same, reassigng back to tuple
    resized_imgs = tuple_resized_imgs(img_plan=data_resized[0],
                                      img_validation=data_resized[1],
                                      ablation_mask=data_resized[2],
                                      tumor_mask=data_resized[3])
```

**Code for "pasting" the ROI segmentations images into a correct size. Might be redundant.:**

```
def paste_roi_image(image_source, image_roi):
    """ Resize ROI binary mask to size, dimension, origin of its source/original img.
        Usage: newImage = paste_roi_image(source_img_plan, roi_mask)

    """
    newSize = image_source.GetSize()
    newOrigin = image_source.GetOrigin()

    newSpacing = image_roi.GetSpacing()
    newDirection = image_roi.GetDirection()

    if image_source.GetSpacing() != image_roi.GetSpacing():
        print('the spacing of the source and derived mask differ')
    # re-cast the pixel type of the roi mask
    pixelID = image_source.GetPixelID()
    caster = sitk.CastImageFilter()
    caster.SetOutputPixelType(pixelID)
    image_roi = caster.Execute(image_roi)

    # black 3D image
    outputImage = sitk.Image(newSize, image_source.GetPixelIDValue())
    outputImage.SetOrigin(newOrigin)
    outputImage.SetSpacing(newSpacing)
    outputImage.SetDirection(newDirection)
    # transform from physical point to index the origin of the ROI image
    # img_center = np.array(img.TransformContinuousIndexToPhysicalPoint(np.array(img.GetSize()) / 2.0))
    destinationIndex = outputImage.TransformPhysicalPointToIndex(image_roi.GetOrigin())
    # paste the roi mask into the re-sized image
    pasted_img = sitk.Paste(outputImage, image_roi, image_roi.GetSize(), destinationIndex=destinationIndex)
    return pasted_img
```